# How to response to request application by using "curl" command in kubernetes cluster nodes?

Tags: curl, networking, kubernetes

I built a k8s cluster(master 1, worker node 5) on ubuntu 18.04.
I confirmed join master and worker nodes.
I used kubeadm, and network add-on flannel. And I have deploy nginx server.

when I command the **curl http://[cluserIP]** on the cluster nodes,but there was no response.

Is the k8s network configuration wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A pod exposed by `clusterIP` type service is only reachable within the cluster. If you do curl from another pod within the cluster it should work. `clusterIP` is not reachable from outside the cluster including even from the nodes itself. If you want to access a pod from nodes via curl expose it via a [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
      # By default and for convenience, the `targetPort` is set to the same value as the `port` field.
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      # Optional field
      # By default and for convenience, the Kubernetes control plane will allocate a port from a range (default: 30000-32767)
      nodePort: 30007
```

With above example `curl http://NODEIP:30007` should work.

Comment: I want to use service, and I commanded curl on master node.
But it did not working. It is problem networking?

Comment: Edit the question to add all yamls and curl command and the error